# Creating an addon that modifies the Ember-cli resolver for 'canary' components

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'd like to create an addon for Ember-cli that modifies the resolver.

After including the addon the resolver would check a cookie that determines whether to first look for components named my-component-canary before falling back to the standard my-component at runtime. This would allow for deploying new canary versions of components that only users with the canary cookie would get.

Are there any examples of addons that modify the resolver? Is this even possible with the currently state of addons?